# proper way to return read-only collection from class property

Tags: c#

in my class I have a property that returns an array of strings, I want to make it read-only. what is the idiomatic way to do this?

right now I have this:

```
class MyClass
{
    string[] MyStrings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's going to depend on context.  What are you going to do with the data, should it reflect changes to the array after the read only object is created, are you concerned with the items inside of the collection being mutated, is making a copy of the data prohibitively expensive, etc.?  Note that there is no one right or wrong answer; what is best in a particular context is based on the answer to those questions (as well as others).

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185166/best-practices-returning-read-only-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always return a copy of the array if your biggest concern is the integrity of your data.

Also look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185166/best-practices-returning-read-only-object, there are some interesting points being made.

Comment: You cannot say that that is the one right option.  It might or might not be the best, given the context.

Comment: That is true, it might not always be the best solution.

Comment: thanks. the link helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array as `IEnumerable<string>` which will allow enumeration only, but it would still be possible to cast it back to `string[]` and modify elements:

```
IEnumerable<string> MyIEnumerableOfStrings { get { return MyStrings; } }
```

Comment: You cannot say that that is the one right option.  It might or might not be the best, given the context.